# javax entity validation is not working for @Min and @Max having same value(like moblieNo should be of exact 10 digits)

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

```
    @NotNull(message = "Mobile number cannot be null.")
@Max(value = 10, message ="Mobile number length should be 10 characters." )
@Min(value = 10, message ="Mobile number length should be 10 characters." )
@Column(name = "mob_no")
private Long mobNo;
```

it should not give the message  "Mobile number length should be 10 characters." in case giving 10 Digits value

Comment: You should consider "accepting" correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have a field defined as Long, which is a number. The @min @max annotations are used for numeric comparison. So actually you say `10 <= mobNo <= 10`. Which means mobNo must be equal to 10.

Interpreting your messages, what you actually want to do is, having a phone number with ten digits (which would be a string and not long). If it is a String the @Size(min,max) annotation can be used. See documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need a `String` instead a `Long` for `mobNo`. Imagine you have a phone number like this: `0005550001`, as a `Long` the value is `550001`. The validation for a `String` should be something like:

```
@Size(min = 10, max = 10, message = "Mobile number length should be 10 characters.")
private String mobNo;
```

Edit:
A good and more comprehensive alternative is to validate against a regular expression matching 10 digits:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\d{10}$", message = "Mobile number length should be 10 characters.")
private String mobNo;
```

Edit:
Adding comment to the answer

If `mobNo` is a `Long` and you can't change it to `String`, validate it with:

```java
@Min(1_000_000_000L)
@Max(9_999_999_999L)
Long mobNo
```

This is the value range where a Long has 10 digits.

However, consider the example above before choosing Long or a phone number field:

Ex:`0_005_550_001`,

this is a valid phone number, but as a `Long` its represented like `550001`.

Comment: private String mobNo; is not in String it is in Long